# Why is my Python code not running correctly in Visual Studio Code, but runs fine in IDLE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-idle

I am currently learning Python and have come across a very strange problem (to me at least). When I type this code:

```
def search4vowels(word):
    """Display any vowels found in a supplied word."""
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    found = vowels.intersection(set(word))
    return bool(found)
```

in an IDLE edit window and run it using IDLE, it all works fine and I need to type my function in at the prompt in order for it to start.

However, when I write the same code in Visual Studio Code and run it using the **Run
Python file in Terminal** option all I get is:

[image: IDE screenshot]

I have also tried the **Code Runner** extension and that gives me a blank output page and no way to type in the function.

**For example**: `search4vowels('galaxy')`

And the output that I expect should be: `True` (Because a vowel would be present in the word, therefore True)

However, nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining function `search4vowels()`, but Visual Studio Code doesn't know how to run it.

Try adding this in your code:

```
def search4vowels(word):
    """Display any vowels found in a supplied word."""
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    found = vowels.intersection(set(word))
    return bool(found)

# This tells your code to run the function search4vowels():
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(search4vowels('your word'))
```

Here is [the manual page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) about the word `"__main__"`.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it